# Not able to print one attribute while remaining are printing to console

Tags: c++

I am implementing a simple program in c++.
I am facing a problem here. I have a student class in which I have fname and lname attributes.
I am returning a student instance from findLoser method. I am able to print the fname but not lname. It is not giving any error. I tried to print the length of lname from getter and it is giving correct result and also i tried to print letter by letter from lname using indexing and it is printing but when I try to print the whole lname it is not printing.
Below all the header and remaining files

```
#ifndef CLIST_HPP
#define CLIST_HPP
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Student{
    private:
        string fname;
        string lname;
        bool seen;
    public:
        Student(){};
        Student(string fname, string lname);
        string getLname(){return this->lname;};
        string getFname(){return this->fname;};
        void setSeen(){seen = !seen;};
        bool getSeen(){return seen;};
};

class Cell{
    public:
        Cell* next;
        Cell* prev;
        Student* student;
};

class Clist{
    public: 
         friend class Cell;
         Clist(){current = nullptr;tracker = nullptr;temp = nullptr; count = 0;}
         void print();
         Cell* current ;
         Cell* tracker;
         Cell* temp ;
         int count;
        Student* findLoser();
        void insert(string fname, string lname);
        
        
};





# endif
```

Above is the header file.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include "Clist.hpp"
using namespace std;

Student::Student(string fname, string lname){
    this->fname = fname;
    this->lname = lname;
    this->seen = false;

}
Student* Clist::findLoser(){
    tracker = current;
    
    int i = current->student->getLname().length()-1;
    while(true){       
        while(i>0){
            tracker = tracker->next;
            i--;
        }
        if(tracker->student->getSeen()){
            return tracker->student;
        }
        else{
            tracker->student->setSeen();
        }    
    }

}
void Clist::print(){
    tracker = current;
    int i =0 ;
    while(i<6){
       cout << tracker -> student->getLname()  << endl;
       tracker = tracker -> next;
       i++;
    }
     
}
void Clist::insert(string fname, string lname){
    Student* student = new Student(fname, lname);
    Cell* newCell =  new Cell();
    newCell->student = student;
    
    if(current == nullptr){
        
        current = newCell;
        newCell-> next  = newCell;
        newCell-> prev =  newCell;
    }
    else{
        temp  = current->prev;
        newCell->next = current;
        temp->next = newCell;
        current-> prev = newCell;
    }
    count++;
}

bool checkIsFileEmpty(ifstream& pFile)
{
    return pFile.peek() == std::ifstream::traits_type::eof();
}




int main(){
    ifstream inputFile("late.txt");
    if(checkIsFileEmpty(inputFile)){
        cout << "Congratulations!!!! to EveryOne No one was Late"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    string name;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    Student* loserStudent;
    Clist* list = new Clist();
    while(true){
        if (inputFile.eof()){
            break;
        }
        getline(inputFile, name);
        size_t spacePos = name.find(' ');
        firstName = name.substr(0, spacePos);
        lastName = name.substr(spacePos + 1);
        list->insert(firstName, lastName);

    }

    loserStudent = list->findLoser();
    cout << loserStudent->getLname();
    cout << loserStudent->getFname();
}
```

and above is the main file.

```
Joe Smith
Paul Jones
Joseph Bryson
Jim Galin
Brian Morrisy
Jane Doe
Raj Patel
```

this is the text file.

Could you please look into the code and point out what I am doing wrong which is stopping me from printing the Lname.

Comment: do you have to implement your own list? Even if you do, I strongly suggest to use `std::list` and write the code you so can easily swap `std::list` with your own. This would allow you to test the list and the rest of the code separately. Also you should use hardcoded input. Reading from the file is just another source of bugs. Are you sure reading from the file works ok?

Comment: your loop is a variation of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong?rq=3.

Comment: Start using a debugger. [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems).

Comment: works fine here https://godbolt.org/z/zadE6vG75

Comment: Program works for me, too. It does, however, contain two major bugs: 1. `Clist::insert` fails to set `newCell->prev = temp;`, and 2. Class `Clist` needs to follow the [Rule of 3 (or5)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). There are a few minor issues, as well, but, depending how the class is used, I wouldn't call them bugs.